# PHP: Imagick converting multi-page pdf into single image issue

Tags: php, image, pdf, imagemagick, imagick

I am trying to convert a multi-page pdf into a single image with all pages in the pdf stacked. I am trying to use the Imagick() class. I found similar questions but none have helped the issue. Here is the code I am using.

```
$img = new Imagick();
$img->setResolution(300, 300);
$img->readImage(example.pdf);
$img->resetIterator();
$imga = $img->appendImages(true);
$imga->setImageFormat('jpg');
$imga->writeImage("pdfs.jpg");
```

Only the last page of the pdf is saved in the jpg file the other pages are not.

I am using ImageMagick-7.0.10, PHP 7.3.12 and I am on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

You,have to add the index of the pdf page you want.
For the first page :

```
$img->readImage(example.pdf[0]);
```

I'm looking to generate animated gif with multipage pdf... not done yet !